# How to make my MVC 4 application able to access from other computer , allow multiple computers to connect to my site on IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an mvc 4 application on IIS 7.5 on my local computer, i do set bindings to my app. but currently it is only accessible one user at a time, when tried to access from another pc it shows an error The "RenderBody" has not been call for layout page. I have already modified the Limits settings > limit number of connections on IIS but still does'nt work!

[This is the error shown ,when i tried to access the site from another computer in a network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jiqc2.png)

[to make other user able access my site successfully without error is to sign out first the currently logged in user,click this link for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e3UJ.png)

and for that,I think my site on IIS don't allow concurrent request, **I need to sign out first in order to make other computer in a network access my site without an error.

When i am currently logged in to my site, it shows an error when i try to access my site from another pc, **The "RenderBody" method has not been called for layout page** How can i deal with that issue?

Comment: That error doesn't sound like it relates to IIS or number of connections. Send us the exact error (print screen for example)

Comment: That error occurs when you have a cshtml file that uses another cshtml file as a layout "Layout = "something.cshtml" and the layout being used "something.cshtml" does not call @RenderBody().  It has to call RenderBody() to specify where the file using the layout get's rendered on the layout.

Comment: @OferZelig i have edited my post above , i have link the detailed picture of erro. hope you can help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with the connections. It sounds like a problem in your layout page. Maybe you're missing the section "@RenderBody()"?

`@RenderBody` works as a placeholder for the engine to know where to drop the content of the view using the layout page

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383145/RenderBody-RenderPage-and-RenderSection-methods-in) a good explanation of the sections you can/need to use.